# Git hook - how to simplify commit query on push?

Tags: git

For listening the git commits, I hook to the push service. And every-time when I do a push, My application gets the call and then I request server for all commits in it and again I request server for all file info in it. to know all detail.

I remember, earlier when push hook trigger the service. it pass all info. But later stage they modified it. Now we have to do multiple call to get full info.

Can this be done simpler?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email), an alternative to webhook would be to use [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/quickstart) in order to, on push, get the commits information, and then [send back the result through email](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email)

> In push event, before and after key are stand for the previous commit of this push operation and the last commit in this push operation.
> All the commits related to the push are included between these two commits.
> [image: pr event]
>
> To get the modified files accossiated with the push event, you could use `git diff` command to get the file names.
>
> ```
> git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.event.after }}
> ```
>
> Also, remember to set fetch-depth: 0 in checkout action.
> Please see my example workflow yml:

```yaml
on:
  push:
jobs:
   build: 
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps: 
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with: 
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: get file changes
        run: | 
          git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.event.after }}
```

You can replace the `git diff` command by a simple `git log`, to get more information than just the names of the files.

The point is: the additional call is done on GitHub side, and the end result is sent back to you, as opposed to the webhook approach when you receive a signal and have to send back an additional query.